# Capturing datagrid cell header click

Tags: .net

I just want to check if a click is made in an datagrid whether the click is made on a header r on a cell content.

I am facing a problem when...

when cell is clicked i am manipulating with the data. But if the header is clicked for sorting ,same cell click event is triggered.

How can i stop this ?

Answer (score 1):

In your event code, check if

```
e.RowIndex >= 0
```

prior to executing the code. If the user clicks on the header cell, the RowIndex will be -1 therefore the code will not be executed.